# Where to put the HTML form, above or below the PHP or it doesn't matter?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm new to PHP. I have a form and a PHP within the same page. My question is, where should I put the PHP block, below? Or above the HTML form?

The reason why I'm asking this is because when I tried to put a default value for one of the input fields,

```
value="<?php echo $variable; ?>",
```

and also when I put a variable holding the error message

```
<span><?php echo $field_err; ?></span>
```

I got an undefined variable error. I can solve this by using the global keyword. But do I really have to do that?

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: You could also let the PHP print out the HTML directly and not have to worry about either...

Comment: You _could_ try the two different approaches out and see if they give any difference ...

Comment: try this instead : `echo (isset($field_err)) ? $field_err : '';` - then you at least get rid of the _undefined variable_ error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better practice is to put PHP **ABOVE** HTML and inside if needed (as your example)

## Reasons:

1. What if you want to redirect? There must not be anything send when redirecting with PHP header()
2. What if there was an error in form validation and you would like to print message on TOP of the form? => you could not do that if PHP would be under the form

However the PHP can be placed anywhere - above, under and **inside** html

Only reasonable placing under the HTML is when including some other content-file, usually `footer.php` or something similar.

**EDIT:** If you want to check if variable exists use PHP's `isset()` if you want to use if your variable is empty, use PHP's `empty()` - but be aware of empty and its behaviour for example:
 `0, "0", array(), NULL, FALSE and ""` are considered as **empty** too => for more info check:

http://php.net/empty
and http://php.net/isset

Answer (score 0):

PHP and almost all languages gets interpreted or compiled from top to down.

Having said that, if you try to use a variable, and this variable is not defined or not in the scope, PHP will not find its value and will alert you.

The undefined variable error indicates that you must define your variables before you use it.

For example:

```
<?php

//We define our variable
$field_err = "";

?>

<span><?php echo $field_err; ?></span>
```

This way, PHP doesn't warn you about an undefined variable, because the variable `$field_err` is defined correctly with an empty string.

You can also be sure that the output HTML will be like this:

```
<span></span>
```

In conclusion, you should always define the variables before using them, no matter where the PHP block is.

Comment: Ok got it thanks. Actually, I defined the variable but based on the answers I get is I should do that before the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your php code any where .it can be bellow and it can be bellow. I thing good practice is if you keep your code in a indivitual file.
Example one

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to read and understand if you place your php code abobe the html, and then you just use the variables to fill the spaces in the html

```
<?php
  $name = "Alex";
?>
<input type="text value="<?=$name?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also break in and out of php as many times as you would like, it can get ugly though.

```
 <html>
 <table>
 <tr><td><?php echo $var;?></td></tr>
 <tr><td><?php echo $var2;?></td></tr>

 <?php 

  if ($var = "1")
  {
?>
  <tr><td>You entered 1</td></tr>
 <?php
 }
 else
 {
 ?>
  <tr><Td>You did not enter 1</td></tr>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
```